# How to remind people to use your Android app if they haven't opened it for quite some time?

Tags: java, android, notifications

Basically I'm developing a social networking app and wanted to know, how I could give possible notifications to the users who have downloaded my app to open the app and use it. It could be on some time period too. But I want to know even when my app isn't running in the background, then how can I give notification to the user to open it and use it?

Comment: just a thought but maybe you can have your app write to some file in storage whenever it is opened.  Then, you have a background service (which runs independent of the app), check this file and send a notif if the last time the app wrote to the file has exceeded some defined time period

Comment: I'd focus on making an app people want to use all the time instead of finding ways to annoy them when they don't.

Answer (score 3):

For reminding you can use alarm manger.
while exiting app sets alarm manager after 3 days.

If user opens app within 3 days then cancel alarm  and while exiting app again set alarm manager

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I want to know what if the user just installed the app and didn't open it even once? Will the notification come then?

Comment: why will a user install an app if he dont want to open it atleast once

Answer (score 0):

whenever the user opens the app store the devices current date in your machine using `SharedPreferences` and keep a service running in the background which will check the systems current date and the date you have stored in your `SharedPreferences` and according to your logic when you think it is too much time give the notification

Links
[SharedPreferences](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23024831/android-shared-preferences-example) &
[service](http://javatechig.com/android/android-service-example)

Comment: Will the service run even if the app hasn't been opened even once?

Comment: why will a user install an app if he dont want to open it atleast once

Comment: That's what I want to know sir

Comment: i said that it wont work until the user has opened it once but that is not logical